# jQuery: Hold horizontal scroll location on window resize

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling

My site is a series of horizontal inline-blocks, each with width: 100%. However when you are far along the horizontal scroll, resizing the window moves the blocks around making it seem like you are losing your scroll position.

To hold the scroll location on resize I have been trying with the following function where currTile() reports the index of the inline-block that is on screen, however it does not seem to be doing the trick

```
onResize();
  function onResize() {
    var desCenter = currTile() * $(window).width();
    $('body').scrollLeft(desCenter);
  }
$(window).resize(onResize);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Have you tried with offset? var desCenter = $('inline-block-elements')[currTile()].offset().left;